# Error in is.data.frame(x) : object '' not found , how could I fix this?

Tags: r, excel, correlation

I'm trying to run correlations on R.

This is my code so far:

```
library("foreign")
mydata<-read.csv(" ",header=FALSE)
options(max.print=1000000)
attach(mydata)
cor(as.numeric(agree_election),as.numeric(agree_party))
```

Then it gives me the error that object "agree_election" is not an object.

However, agree_election is just one of the headers of my columns for my excel spreadsheet.How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you include a `dput` of `mydata` ? even the output of `str(mydata)` would help.

Comment: you have used `header=FALSE` and hence `mydata` has no column named `agree election`, try with `header=TRUE`. Also, using `attach` could be dangerous, I would recommend against its usage since attached objects could be easily overwritten. Using `mydata$agree_election` is safer approach.

Answer (score 1):

Check the names in your data frame! Does it contain a variable with a name `agree_election`?

Please avoid the `attach` function. It could be fine with just one data frame, but it can make a mess if you have several data frames attached.

This could should be fine, if the variable names are correct.

```
mydata <- read.csv("...", header = F)
names(mydata)
str(mydata)
cor(as.numeric(mydata$agree_election), as.numeric(mydata$agree_party))
```